# Unexpected Result when data source has null values in Mosaic Decisions

Tags: mosaic-decisions

I am designing a data pipeline in **Mosaic Decisions**. I have a database where some values in the data are **nulls**. I require to use a **CustomSQL** Node to query the database, but due to these **Null** values, the result is unexpected

How can I avoid such situations and convert the **nulls** into some other values before adding the **customSQL**.

I have previously used another **customSQL** just to replace all the **null** values. However, I need to keep adding complex queries to do that. Is there any other possible way to achieve the same thing without the use of separate **customSQL** node to handle the **null** values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mosaic Decisions** has recently introduced a new **Process Node**. The **Impute Process Node** is capable of handling the **null** values present in the dataset.

You can follow these steps below to get rid of the **null** values in your data with the help of the **Impute Node** and avoid using the complex **SQL** queries in the **CustomSQL Node.**

1. After dragging in the **Impute Node** into the canvas and connecting the input, open the configuration menu.
2. Drag and drop the **column(s)** you would like to handle your **null** values on.
3. From the list of **Impute Strategies**, select the most suitable choice based on the data type of your column(s). You can either select same or different **strategies** on the selected column(s) and **Add** them.


   [image: impute node configuration]


   [image: added impute strategies]

Refer the **user manual** under the help section for **detailed information** on the **Impute Strategies**.

You can direct the output of this node directly to your **CustomSQL Node** where you are writing the main **query** for your **data pipeline**.